# mySQL searching for multi accounters

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to search for multi-accounters in a cleaner method than what follows?  I am searching for this in logs, having multiple accounts isn't against the rules, but I would like to know who is multi accounting.

```
SELECT a.username, a.ipaddr
FROM logs AS a
INNER JOIN logs AS b ON a.ipaddr = b.ipaddr
AND a.username <> b.username
GROUP BY a.username
ORDER BY a.ipaddr
```

If I concat a.username and b.username, then I will get the same thing as expanding brackets i.e. (a + b)(c + d) when I want to get something like this: a, b, c, d

If this is still not clear, here is an example of the above query:

```
username, ipaddress
bob, 1.2.3.4
tom, 1.2.3.4
joe, 1.2.3.4
sally, 2.3.4.5
jenny, 2.3.4.5
bob2, 2.3.4.5
```

When I would like to return something as follows:

```
username, ipaddress
bob & tom & joe, 1.2.3.4
sally & jenny & bob2, 2.3.4.5
```

How can I do this? I cannot think of any ways without using hundreds of sub queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group_concat with a distinct select subquery:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.username SEPARATOR ' & ') as username,
    a.ipaddr
FROM (select distinct username,ipaddr from logs) AS a
GROUP BY a.ipaddr
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY a.ipaddr
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9211/2

**EDIT** Added `HAVING count(*) > 1` to only get mult-accounters.

Answer (score 1):

Try with GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.username SEPARATOR ' & ') as username, a.ipaddr
FROM logs AS a
INNER JOIN logs AS b ON a.ipaddr = b.ipaddr
AND a.username <> b.username
GROUP BY a.username
ORDER BY a.ipaddr
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but then it would just return the same username hundreds of times per row.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have solved it based off of using GROUP_CONCAT as per Sadikhasan's suggestion

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( username ) , ipaddr
FROM (

SELECT a.username, a.ipaddr
FROM LOGS AS a
INNER JOIN LOGS AS b ON a.ipaddr = b.ipaddr
AND a.username <> b.username
GROUP BY a.username
ORDER BY a.ipaddr
)a
GROUP BY a.ipaddr
```